Why do my ways not show in OSM, but the attached name tag does?
I just created my first contribution to OSM yesterday, and can see some results now. However, as the title implicates, I do have some questions.

I created a polygon for a holding area in the waters between Germany and Denmark. The ways have the following tags

and the only thing shown in OSM is the name, but not the polygon for the holding area.
If I switch to OpenSeaMap, I can see the polygon for the holding area. The tag seamark:name was added later and is most likely not yet reflected.
I checked the tags for the polygon "Sperrgebiet Marienleuchte", just south of the polygon I created and would say they are basically the same, except that I had to add the 'construction' tag because of my value for the 'landuse'-tag.
How do I get the polygon to show in OSM, and not only in OpenSeaMap?

Sperrgebiet Marienleuchte has the tag landuse=military which leads to it getting rendered (the red outline with the red lines inside represents a military area).
Your Femern Fixed Link Holding Area North has landuse=construction instead. I guess the renderer has no rule for how to render a construction site in a water area (or it simply renders water bodies above construction areas since this makes sense for the mainland).
I wouldn't worry too much about this. In any case, don't get the idea to add random tags until your area shows up. This would be tagging for the renderer and is highly discouraged.

Thanks @scai, what you write does give meaning and I will certainly not add random tags to force the OSM algorithm to render the area. Maybe the conclusion is that OSM is not the right tool for the job...

Though it does not make much sense to place the label of an area without the area.

Keep in mind that OSM is actually just a database. Not a rendered map. What you are referring to is the so-called standard layer on https://openstreetmap.org/. There are other layers available, each with a different style. And there are hundreds of other OSM-based maps and other applications available. Every tool is free to decide how to render/interpret their OSM-based data. So far your goal is not quite clear. Maybe you can use https://uMap.openstreetmap.de/ to change the way the map looks like by adding a visible polygon on top of this construction area.

Thanks for the link to uMap.openstreetmap.de. Okay, I am a bit puzzled how my goal is not clear.  I would like to see name and polygon for the holding area in openstreetmap.org. Thinking about "...or it simply renders water bodies above construction areas since this makes sense for the mainland", I would argue that it does not make sense. Either the construction site is correct and the water body needs to be adjusted, or the polygon of the construction site cannot overlap with water bodies and needs to be adjusted. But this might not be the place for this discussion. ;-)

Agreed, this might not be the best choice for overlapping water bodies and construction sits. If you want you can discuss this specific issue with the maintainers of the standard rendering style by creating a ticket at https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/issues/
